# Display latest entry among objects of same property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Here is my array of objects.

```
const testData = [
  {
    latest_id: 460,
    data_name: 'cust_mobile',
    data_value: 'sd2 '
  },
  {
    latest_id: 454,
    data_name: 'cust_mobile',
    data_value: 'sdXX '
  },
  {
    latest_id: 461,
    data_name: 'cust_mobile',
    data_value: 'sd4'
  },
  {
    latest_cust_id: 15,
    data_name: 'cust_pin',
    data_value: '12412'
  },
  {
    latest_cust_id: 485,
    data_name: 'cust_pin',
    data_value: '545455'
  },

  {
    latest_address_id: 485,
    data_name: 'cust_address',
    data_value: 'fsdf dfsf'
  }
];
```

My target is to compare the data_name property of each object and objects having the same data_name property value, I want to display corresponding data_value property value but it must be the latest entry.

For example, If we consider cust_mobile property value (total 3 occurrence among all objects in the example) then it should display data_value of "sd4" (here sd4 is the latest entry).

Can somebody please suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: by latest entry are you refering to the newest added entry(time related) or to the last entry in the list of items that have the same `data_name`

Comment: Its last entry in the list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function getLatestObject(array, propertyName, value) {
  return array.reverse().find(item => item[propertyName] === value);
}
```

Example:

```
getLatestObject(testData, 'data_name', 'cust_mobile')
> {latest_id: 461, data_name: "cust_mobile", data_value: "sd4"}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the "last entry item" considered as the last appearance in the array,
you might want to firstly reverse the array with[`#Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and then find the item with [`#Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
arrayShallowCopy.reverse().find(predicate)
```

```js
const testData = [{
    "latest_id": 460,
    "data_name": "cust_mobile",
    "data_value": "sd2 "
  },
  {
    "latest_id": 454,
    "data_name": "cust_mobile",
    "data_value": "sdXX "
  },
  {
    "latest_id": 461,
    "data_name": "cust_mobile",
    "data_value": "sd4"
  },
  {
    "latest_cust_id": 15,
    "data_name": "cust_pin",
    "data_value": "12412"
  },
  {
    "latest_cust_id": 485,
    "data_name": "cust_pin",
    "data_value": "545455"
  },

  {
    "latest_address_id": 485,
    "data_name": "cust_address",
    "data_value": "fsdf dfsf"
  }

];

const predicate = entry => entry.data_name === "cust_mobile";
const arrayShallowCopy = [...testData];

console.log(arrayShallowCopy.reverse().find(predicate));
```